# how to call different tables in if and else part of the same database in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

I have a database. It has two tables in it. I want to call one table in if condition. If if conditions fails i wanted to call the second table in the else part.

Can any one help by providing the sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is super-simple:

```
char *tableName = (somecondition) ? "someTable" : "someOtherTable";
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database is it? If sqlite, simply modify sql command with the condition.

```
NSString* sql;
if (cond) {
    sql = @"SELECT id from foo;";
} else {
    sql = @"SELECT * from bar;";
}
```